# Why overlap in an assignment expression must be exact and the objects must have the same type, and what does it mean?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Browsing through [Enumeration of Core Undefined Behavior](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1705r1.html?), I stumbled upon the [[expr.ass] case](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1705r1.html?fbclid=IwAR1kYRaUXdk2MuAm9BNgy4pIAvUzfdmbAIM2TSw6OpSAhcQ_BFpQb2aWsjs#exprass). An example is given:

```
int x = 1;
char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x);
x = *c;
```

What exactly is wrong with this code? Is it because it accesses `x` on both sides of the operand, but one of them is via aliasing pointer? Would this fix:

```
int x = 1;
char* c = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x);
int y = *c;
x = y;
```

Be sufficient, then? If not, is it actually illegal to access *any parts* of an object via `char*` (assuming that object's `sizeof` is greater than `char`'s, for the sake of keepig the "*parts*" part)? If yes, how come serialization to binary works, since it relies on aliasing a given object with (possibly cv-qualified) `char*`, followed by pushing (which requires dereferencing, similarily to above example) separate bytes to a stream?

Comment: _and what does it mean?_ As it was discussed a couple of month ago in core reflector, this wording could prolly apply only to bit-fields sharing some storage.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer then why an example consists of code with no bit-fields? Is the example incorrect?

Comment: Ignoring the current potentially defective wording in [conv.lval] and in all other related places, it is not clear  if `*c` reads the value of `x`, when [expr.ass] says «If the value being stored in an object is read via another object that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object...». It is questionable if we have a `char` object, for example. Or if it is within its lifetime etc.

Comment: There is a proposal to have `reinterpret_cast` create objects, but it's not the case yet. So there is no object of type `char` and the example seems incorrect. See also DR [556](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#556)

Comment: @rustyx: Has there ever been a good reason for a compiler to use an abstraction model that couldn't readily accommodate the use of a pointer formed by `reinterpret_cast` to access storage associated with an object of the original type *at least within the context of the cast*, or within nested contexts *wherin the object is accessed exclusively by pointers based upon the new one*?  I know that the maintainers of gcc decided to adopt such a broken model and have been adamantly defending it ever since, but was there ever any good reason for gcc or any other compiler to have done so?

Comment: @rustyx: IMHO, both the C and C++ Committees should formally recognize a corollary of simple principle that described in the C Committee's charter (nor sure about C++) as "don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done"; I'd express the corollary as "If omitting some part of the Standard would make it easy to accomplish some task in defined fashion, the Standard should provide a comparably easy way of accomplishing that task in defined fashion."  Unfortunately, the authors of clang and gcc would block anything that would require them to support...

Comment: ...semantics that don't fit their abstraction model, or suggest that an inability to support what should be simple operations might make their compiler inferior to others that can support such things.

Comment: With regard to the "enumeration of UB" concept, the right approach to handling many forms of Undefined Behavior would be to go back to recognizing the major strength of pre-standard C: the ability of the core language to fit range of abstraction models which could be appropriate for various platforms and purposes.  There's no way any one abstraction model could be a reasonable fit all purposes, but one wouldn't need very many to accommodate the extremely vast majority of purposes.  For example, consider the following three guarantees about integer overflow:

Comment: 1. Signed integer addition, subtraction, and multiplication will always wrap cleanly without side effects; 2. Such math may cause an abnormal program termination in case of overflow, but will never be observed to produce an arithmetically-incorrect result; 3. Signed integer addition, subtraction, and multiplication, may cause abnormal termination as with #2 or yield meaningless results, but will have no *other* side effects.  Some programs' needs wouldn't be met by #1, and some wouldn't be met by #2, but almost all would be met by either #1 or #2, and any that would be met by #3...

Comment: ...would be equally usable on implementations supporting either of the first two.

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms, given something like `long *x,*y,*z;` the most efficient way of processing `*x = *y + *z;` may be to:

- Add the low-order word of `*y` to the low-order word of `*z`, noting the carry, and store the result into the low order word of `*x`.
- Add the high-order word of `*y` to the high-order word of `*z`, along with any carry from the previous step, and store that to the high-order word of `*x`.

If the low-order word of `*x` coincided with the high order word of `*y`, performing operations in that sequence would result in the high-order word of `*y` getting overwritten before it was used in the expression.

Note that with clang and gcc, limitations on overlap are not limited to primitive types.  A related issue arises with a construct like:

```
struct s { int x[2]; };

int test(struct s *p1, struct s *p2)
{
  if (*(p1->x))
    *(p2->x+1) = 1;
  return *p1->x;
}
```

Here, all actual loads and stores are done by dereferencing pointers of type `int*`, rather than type `struct s*`, gcc's generated code requires that either `p1` and `p2` identify the same instance of `struct s`, or disjoint instances, and may malfunction if they identify overlapping instances.

Comment: "*If the low-order word of *x coincided with the high order word of *y, performing operations in that sequence would result in the high-order word of *y getting overwritten before it was used in the expression.*" - how can this happen if we can only alias with `char` (which is introduced in the example), which is not permitted (indirectly) to not be represented as more than 1 word? In addition, how come `p1` and `p2` identify different, overlapping instances? Something very wrong must've happened first, presumably by broken placement-new usages. Is my though process correct?

Comment: @Fureeish: The overlap rules in C++ are derived from those of C, which has no concept of "placement new".  In C, if one had e.g. `union foo {long x; struct q { int y; long z; }} u;`, then on some platforms `u.x` and `y.q.z` would overlap.  The behavior of `long temp = u.q.z; u.x = temp+12345;` would be perfectly well defined even on such platforms, and in the absence of the no-overlap rule, there would be no reason why `long *p1=&u.x, *p2 = &u.q.z; *p1 = *p2 + 1234;` wouldn't be defined likewise.

Comment: The union example sounds really weird, because it does seem like some subtle differences and rules regarding pointers to its (possible inactive) members may interfere. I do, however, acknowledge that the example is extremely interesting nonetheless. Word-wise copying between `union` members seems like a devil's work. Although I am still not sure whether a compiler could break something like that. Those elements are copied into registers, modified, and then stored back - despite the pointers.

Comment: @Fureeish: As noted in my answer, when operating with values larger than a word, it may be more efficient on some platforms to perform all of the operations on the low-order byte of each word, and then perform all operations on the high-order byte.  Among other things, computing a result in registers before writing anything back would tie up two registers holding the result, while processing the high and low bytes separately may make an extra register available for other purposes (like holding another loop index without having to save/restore it on each iteration of the loop).

Comment: I think it kind of makes sense now, but I really don't want it to...

Comment: _Note that with clang and gcc, limitations on overlap are not limited to primitive types_ It is definitely not because of [expr.ass] rule. [Subclause \[expr.compound\] defines the effects of operators when applied to types for which they have not been overloaded](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.pre). So the restriction on partial overlap just doesn't apply to non-builtin types.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: If the Standard were to adopt an abstraction model where the combined actions of forming a pointer to one type from a pointer to, or lvalue of, another type, and the subsequent use of that pointer, were regarded as potential actions on the original object that were generally unsequenced with regard to anything that occurs between the formation and use of the pointer, then the limitations on overlapping object actions would serve the same purpose as aliasing rules, but would be easier for both programmers and compilers to work with.